# Maven : How to resolve the version conflict of the same jar package?

Tags: java, maven

My maven project is using `dbcp-1.4` and `jedis-2.4.2`. But `dbcp-1.4` relies on `commons-pool-1.5.4` and `jedis-2.4.2` relies on `commons-pool2-2.0`.

How do I resolve this kind of problem ?

Comment: Hi,Better you use DBCP 2.0 which supports commons pool 2 and jedis same version also supports commons pool 2...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming commons-pool2-2.0 is backwards compatible with 1.5.4, in the pom.xml you can declare the dependency of dbcp with exclusions of the commons pool transitive dependency.
Ex:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      **<exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>group-c</groupId>
          <artifactId>excluded-artifact</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>**
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <type>bar</type>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```